# Magento: How to manage partial ship for BackOrders?

Tags: magento

Any way to manage partial shipment ?

Scenario:
 - I have a customer that order some items ( some of them are in backorder status )
 - I want to ship him items that I have in stock and mark them
 - put the order in partial ship status

Any way to do that ? any hint for creating an extension doing that ?

Comment: I was found an extension from MLX-STORE. You can try it http://www.mlx-store.com/magento-extensions/sales/split-order-for-magento.html Have good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, you can create two or more shipments for a single order and
>   specify a tracking number for each shipment.  From the order, click on
>   ship.  From there you can add a tracking number and specify the qty
>   that will be shipped.

See @ https://web.archive.org/web/20121226192320/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/194148

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember ... btw I think you answer should be a comment ...